# How to get number of subscribers to Youtube Channel?

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

I used this code...

```
$youtube_url = json_decode( file_get_contents( 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/channelname?v=2&alt=json' ), true );
$youtube_data = $youtube_url['entry']['yt$statistics']['subscriberCount'];
```

...but there is an error:

> "Warning: file_get_contents(http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/nikitaplay?v=2&alt=json) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 410 Gone in..."

I am bad in PHP, so I don't understand this error

**UPDATE**:
Also I used this code...

```
$youtube_url = json_decode( file_get_contents( 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id=d1chArLU0voGrMzbUM4G-A&key=AIzaSyCwAooaPaSzPEcDBULe-7jI3XZ6ZYRmiNY' ), true );
```

...but there is an error:

> Warning: file_get_contents(https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id=d1chArLU0voGrMzbUM4G-A&key=AIzaSyCwAooaPaSzPEcDBULe-7jI3XZ6ZYRmiNY) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden in...

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO, please take some time to read the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). As your question is now it lacks a lot of information, both in the form of what is going wrong, but also what errors you are getting, simply stating that "It doesn't work" doesn't tell us much. So please update your question with as much useful information to the question as you can :)

Comment: API v2 is no longer available, use API v3

Comment: mpgn, I know this, and that is why I asked this question

Answer (score 0):

1) Log in to a Google account and go to https://console.developers.google.com/. You may have to start a new project.

2) Navigate to APIs & auth and go to Public API Access -> Create a New Key

3) Choose the option you need (I used 'browser applications') This will give you an API key.

4) Navigate to your channel in YouTube and look at the URL. The channel ID is here: https://www.youtube.com/channel/YOUR_CHANNEL_ID

5) Use the API key and channel ID to get your result with this query: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id=YOUR_CHANNEL_ID&key=YOUR_API_KEY

Comment: But there is an error: Warning: file_get_contents(https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id=d1chArLU0voGrMzbUM4G-A&key=AIzaSyCwAooaPaSzPEcDBULe-7jI3XZ6ZYRmiNY) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden in...

Answer (score -1):

Get an API Key for **Youtube v3** in https://console.developers.google.com

```
$apiKey = 'puthereyouapikey';
$chanelId = 'channelid';
$json = json_decode((file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id='.$channelId.'&key='.$apiKey)), true);
echo ($json != NULL) ? (($json['items']['0']['statistics']['subscriberCount'])) : '';
```